# keep getting rake aborted! Stack level too deep while compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I keep getting this error while compiling my assets of my rails app, I tried --trace and this is the output

```
WARNING: DSL method Object#ruby called at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3- p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
WARNING: DSL method Object#ruby called at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'

rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/ostruct.rb:173
```

here is my codes:
https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/PlotApp

Any suggestions on this???

Comment: Stack level too deep basically means infinite loop

Comment: the warning shows there is some problem with the file_utility module i am requiring in the application.rb file...is there a prob?? How can I get over this??

Comment: How are you requiring it? It might be self-referencing something, which causes the infinite loop. Can you post some more info about what your `file_utility` module is, and what its contents are?

Comment: its here:
https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/PlotApp/blob/master/config/application.rb

Comment: Okay, first looks - why are you including those files in `application.rb`? Surely they should go into [`initializers`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers)? I've never had to include Paperclip in application.rb before - what is fileutils? Is it a gem? If it is, I'll take a look at the code for it

Comment: should I include them in controller??

Comment: FileUtility is a module available in ruby... http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html

Comment: Nope - either in an intializer or another file. Why are you requiring Paperclip? If you can detail what you're actually requiring, I'll be in a better position to write some new code for you

Comment: The program requires file uploads and for that I am using paperclip..?? I require paperclip both in Predict and Upload controller..it takes the file saves in public folder and the meta data goes in database

Comment: Hmmm, having looked it up (I've never used FileUtils before), it seems that since it's part of the Ruby core, you should just be able to use it in your controllers / models by calling `FileUtils.method` ? Perhaps requiring it will be trying to load something which exists already!

Comment: ohh OK.. now I got the point..

Comment: Okay, I'm getting confused because [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) doesn't need to be required - it just works in the backend. It should work with your models when you call `has_attached_file`

Comment: Try removing the `require` for `fileutils` and then see if your methods work again

Comment: nooo again that same above mentioned stack level... ERROR :(

Comment: Did you manage to compile at all before? If so, remove anything you have added, so that it will compile again. Then we can add little parts each time to get it to work

Comment: noo..its just like i was working in development and today I tried to deploy this app on server..so tried compiling for the first time..!!

Comment: So it works in dev but not on the server?

Comment: When I get into the office, I'll try and pull your app to see if it will create same error on my system. Have you tried precompiling in local?

Comment: opps sorry I forgot to mention..i am trying precompiling locally..

Comment: Thanks for the effort Rich..I appreciate..

Comment: Hi, it worked on the server. I guess it was some system specific issue as I upgraded the app from rails v=2.x.x to 3.x.x 
On the server I was able to pre-compile my assets which was not possible locally.

Comment: It could be an incompatibility in Ruby?